# Gradle subproject installDist dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with two subprojects, and am having problems getting the installDist to recognise when it is up-to-date. I have a main `build.gradle` for the project `projName`, which has a subproject `subproj1` which compiles fine, and another subproject `exec` which has the following tasks:

```
  task makeMyExec(type: Copy) {

  dependsOn(':projName.exec:installDist')
  copy {
  from rootProject.file("projName/build/install/exec/")
  into rootProject.file("../myExec/")
  }
}

def createScript(project, mainClass, name) {

  project.tasks.create(name: name, type: CreateStartScripts) {
    outputDir       = new File(project.buildDir, 'scripts')
    mainClassName   = mainClass
    applicationName = name
    classpath       = 
    project.tasks[JavaPlugin.JAR_TASK_NAME].outputs.files + 
    project.configurations.runtime
  }
  project.tasks[name].dependsOn(project.jar)

  project.applicationDistribution.with {
    into("bin") {
      from(project.tasks[name])
      fileMode = 0755
      }
    }
 }
```

Then in the subproject `exec` I have the following lines of its `build.gradle`

```
 apply plugin: 'application'

 dependencies {
    compile project(':subproj1')    
 }

 startScripts.enabled = false
 run.enabled = false

 createScript(project, 'projName.exec.exec1Main', 'script1')
 createScript(project, 'projName.exec.exec2Main', 'script2')
 createScript(project, 'projName.exec.exec3Main', 'script3')
```

The idea is that each of the scripts `script1`, `script2` and `script3` should be added to the `installDist` of subproject `exec`, so that they need to be created before the copy command runs. Unfortunately the copy command always run first.

This means if I run this twice everything copies properly and I get the scripts in the right place, but unfortunately not if I run it just once.

I would very much appreciate help working out what I have wrong with the dependency here, either the dependency on `subproj1` in `exec`, or the dependency of `installDist` in the `makeMyExec` task.

For info - if I only have one mainClass in the subproject and define only

```
mainClassName ='projName.exec.exec1Main'
applicationName = 'script1'
```

then this works as intended and all the libs and scripts are built before the copy is done, as the dependency on installDist seems to work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the solution to this problem. If I modify the `makeMyExec` task to:

```
task makeMyExec(type: Copy) {

  dependsOn('installDist','script1','script2','script3')
  from rootProject.file("projName/build/install/exec/")
  into rootProject.file("../myExec/")
}
```

this remove the necessity for the line:

```
project.tasks[name].dependsOn(project.jar)
```

and adds the dependency to the copy task of the installDist of the main project and each of the subtasks `script1`, `script2` and `script3`.

My mistake was to misunderstand that the `project.applicationDistribution.with` did not actually update the status of `:projName.exec:installDist`